# CSS убрать дубликаты

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, не подскажите сервис или приложение при помощи которого можно убрать дубликаты и ошибки CSS? Находил сайты которые только их находят, но не устраняют

Comment: Поразительно....дубликат о дубликатах

Comment: @АлексейШиманский как будто перед добавлением вопроса я должен пересмотреть каждый на этом сайте, чтобы узнать нет ли подобного

Comment: Да, должен! Для этого есть поиск на сайте, чтобы перед тем как выпаливать свою срочную проблему, которая вовсе **неуникальна**, можно было просмотреть схожие темы и не тратить время всех зря

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вас кто-то заставляет заходить на страницу этого вопроса и тратить своё время?

Comment: Вот, если вы не читали **[справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**, прямо цитата из  нее "Прежде чем задать вопрос...

Сначала убедитесь, **что такой вопрос не задавался ранее**. Воспользуйтесь вашим любимым поисковиком и/или встроенным поиском, поищите и по другим ключевым словам тоже, и даже на второй странице выдачи"

Comment: Речь не конкретно обо мне, а обо всех абсолютно участниках ....и Прежде чем пользоваться ресурсом - ознакомьтесь с правилами. Пока ваши претензии абсолютно бестолковы